# Scraping multiple urls on Kickstarter using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape from the kickstarter website data about the number of backers for each category of rewards for each project.
My imput is a list of urls.

I am encountering a number of problems:

1. I am not able to load from a txt file the urls, but my code works only if the list is in python.

   An example of the data Im trying to scrape is this (actually below there is a piece of the data I scraped from the 2 links in my code below):

   .....
   .....
   , 
   Pledge CA$ 500 or more

   About €325

   , 
   Pledge CA$ 2,500 or more

   About €1,625

   , 
   5 backers
   , 
   2 backers
   ,
   ........
   .......
2. I need to write the results shown above in a row of a CSV file for each project. So the first cell of the CSV file would be the project link (or title, if scraped with beautifulsoup); the second column should be a series of values that consist of the number of backers for each offer. An example using the data above:

`"project link"  ,  "pledge__backer-count" 5 backers   ,   "pledge__amount" $500`

I am struggling with the part of the code that goes from the urls list on. The first part is copied from an example on the web and works well.
Thanks in advance for the help, I really need this for my thesis.
"""

```
from requests import get
from requests.exceptions import RequestException
from contextlib import closing
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

def simple_get(url):
    """
    Attempts to get the content at `url` by making an HTTP GET request.
    If the content-type of response is some kind of HTML/XML, return the
    text content, otherwise return None
    """
    try:
        with closing(get(url, stream=True)) as resp:
            if is_good_response(resp):
                return resp.content
            else:
                return None

    except RequestException as e:
        log_error('Error during requests to {0} : {1}'.format(url, str(e)))
        return None

def is_good_response(resp):
    """
    Returns true if the response seems to be HTML, false otherwise
    """
    content_type = resp.headers['Content-Type'].lower()
    return (resp.status_code == 200 
            and content_type is not None 
            and content_type.find('html') > -1)

def log_error(e):
    """
    It is always a good idea to log errors. 
    This function just prints them, but you can
    make it do anything.
    """
    print(e)



urls=['https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/socialismmovie/socialism-an-american-story?ref=home_potd','https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/1653847368/the-cuban-a-film-about-the-power-of-music-over-alz?ref=home_new_and_noteworthy']


for url in urls:
        Project_raw=simple_get(url)
        Project_bs4= BeautifulSoup(Project_raw, 'lxml')

        Backers_offers=Project_bs4.find_all("h2", class_="pledge__amount")
        Backers_per_offer=Project_bs4.find_all("span", class_="pledge__backer-count")
        Offers_plus_Backers=Backers_offers+Backers_per_offer

        print(Offers_plus_Backers)
```